# Dynamically call PL/SQL procedure with output variables

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I'm trying to use dynamic sql to execute a procedure and retrieve the output parameters:

```
v_sql := 'BEGIN ' || p_procname || '(''' || p_input1 || ''', ''' || p_input2 || ''', v_output1); END;';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
```

I have the `v_output1` variable declared, but I get this error message:

```
PLS-00201: identifier 'V_ISSUE' must be declared
```

The procedure works if I replace the above code with the dbms_ouput from `v_sql`, so it's OK on the procedure side, the issue is somewhere in how I'm trying to call it dynamically.

I don't know if what I'm trying to do will work this way.  Is there a way to retrieve the output parameters from this procedure call through dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use string concatenation to pass parameters to dynamic SQL. It's considered a bad practice at all, not only for Oracle.

It's a bad, but main point of failure is using name of local variable inside dynamic SQL string, because it not visible anywhere outside code block where this variable was introduced.

Your code should look like this:

```
declare 
  v_sql varchar2(4000);
  p_procname varchar2(100);
  p_input1 number;
  p_input2 number;
  v_output1 number;   
begin

  v_sql := 'begin ' || p_procname || '(:p_input1, :p_input2, :v_output); end;';

  execute immediate v_sql 
  using in p_input1, in p_input2, out v_output1;

end;
```

Comment: `p_procname` is a variable too though, and you can't bind that, so you have to concatenate it as Paul is doing in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

Found my answer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/11_dynam.htm#CACDDACH).

```
v_sql := 'BEGIN ' || p_procname || '(:a, :b, :c); END;';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql
USING IN p_input1, IN p_input2, OUT v_output1;
```

Comment: Well done for finding the answer yourself *8-) However, one of the main reasons to use bind variables over string concatenation is to prevent SQL injection. Since you can't bind the procedure name, if you really do have to have that as a passed-in variable, you need to somehow verify that no injection is being attempted, perhaps by checking a proc of that name does exist in the data dictionary, and using it as a bind variable in that query.

Comment: @AlexPoole dbms_utility.name_resolve should probably handle this